# How to get correct reference in R vector equation

Tags: r

I need to update a lot of columbs through a loop. I run into format problems. This work:

```
 data.all$`Daimler AG` [data.all$CIQ_NAME == "Daimler AG"] <- 1
```

But this doesent work:

```
data.all$z[i] [data.all$CIQ_NAME == z[i]] <- 1
```

Z is a vector of names. z[1]="Daimler AG". The loop is runnning through 200 companies

How do i reference a vector in an equation?

Comment: You can't pass variables to `$` for subsetting. Use `[[` instead.

Comment: i am new in R.. how would that look...?

Comment: data.all[[z[i]]] instead. See ?Extract for more details, and read carefully and experiment with the examples.

Comment: Joran ; it works... i will study the extract. Thanks a lot for your hint. It was somehow really a showstopper for me